# The rails way to create a complex user structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, authentication

I'm newbie in rails and I would like to know how should I do something like this:

I'm creating an app with two main user groups, let's call them customers and vendors.

How should I implement this, keeping in mind those similarites and differences:

Differences:

- From the business point of view these two groups are separate, in general customers are buy from vendors.
- They are associated mostly with different models, vendors 90% of time use backend of the app and customers only frontend.
- User account manamegent is quite different

Similarities:

- For both I would like to use some role based authorization solution (ex. [declarative authorization](https://github.com/stffn/declarative_authorization))
- They both log in
- There are rare situations where both interact with the same models through the same controllers/views

What is the best solution to keep it simple and clean at the same time? One fat User model associeted with both customers' and vendors' models? Separate models with duplicated log in logic (how would it works with declarative authorization)? Single table inheritance (again what about declarative authorization)?

Comment: You're taking on a solution to multiple things that most people solve individually.  You are trying to do role base authorization, and have customer and vendor data entities in your data model.  Not that it's bad, but other programmers' experience may be different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a `User` class that handles stuff like authorization and whatever other basic functionality all users of your system have. Then create separate `Customer` and `Vendor` classes that inherit from `User` and have their own business logic. STI in Rails makes it very simple - create a `type` column and it will automatically populate with the class name.

You can use a gem like [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) to segregate the permissions of each type of `User`.

Comment: I agree.  Add a Role class and a many-to-many between User and Role.  I name that RoleMembership.  I do the authorization in a before_filter in the ApplicationController.  I also have a table with which roles can access which Controllers.

Comment: Thanks I'm gonna go that way, hope STI will not couse problems with using gems such as CanCan or Declarative Authorization

Answer (score 1):

OK, I was taking a StackOverflow break at work, and then work called me away, so I replied quickly.  You will have to decide if you want to use STI,

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |table|
      table.string   "type"
...
```

and store your Vendor and Customer object instances in your users table, or use Multiple Table Inheritance, where you just simple have

```
class Vendor < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
...
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
...
```

You will need MTI if you ever have state data specific to your Vendor and/or Customer object, such as Vendor's sale rep, or Customer's purchase history.  OK, purchase history is likely to be a join to other tables which belongs_to :customer, but it may seem awkward to have the joined records belongs_to :user, when a User can be a Vendor.

Now, for the tie in to access control, ... I have implemented an access_control_items table,

```
class CreateAccessControlItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table "access_control_items", :force => true do |table|
      table.timestamps
      table.string   "controller"
      table.string   "action"
      table.string   "group_type", :null => false
      table.integer  "group_id",   :null => false
    end
  end
end
```

The key thing is that I decoupled membership in the role from the access control, and made it polymorphic, so it could be membership in any object with an include?(user) method.  My application controller before method sends the user currently logged in, to the include? method of the group referenced by any access_control_items matching for the controller and action.

So the group could point to an instance of some ActiveRecord class, an that class might be one that responds true to include?(user) if the user is a vendor (has type = "Vendor" in STI, or has_one :vendor not nil in MTI).

In practice, go ahead an use a gem, cancan if you like.  But consider the example for decoupling a design for your own application logic.